# How to avoid gap between action bar and list in List navigation mode?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have an activity with AB + list navigation mode. In my manifest file `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` is set for this activity.
When i open list from AB and rotate device in landscape mode list is still visible, but there is a gap now between AB and list (due to AB changes it's heigh while orientation change).

How do I correctly handle this situation or how can I avoid it at all?

This situation is similar both for the devices with API 8+ and 11+

portrait

[image: portrait]

and landscape

[image: landscape]

Edited.
I've created sample project for android 4.0+ w/o ABS. Result is the same

> private ActionBar mActionBar;
>       private static String[] array = {"Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4","Item4"};

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mActionBar.getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    mActionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, new OnNavigationListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
            Log.d("tag", "Item position " + itemPosition);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

> 

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ablmtest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: That's odd. From your tag, I am assuming that you are using ActionBarSherlock. If so, I'd create a sample app that demonstrates a problem, then file an issue on the project, assuming that there isn't an existing issue for this.

Comment: I've just created sample API14 project with native ActionBar - the problems is still the same. It looks like a some kind of bug.

Comment: Post the project somewhere, so we can see if we can reproduce it.

Comment: Posted code in question